# ESP32 espressif-IDF: error while using 'idf.py build' command

Tags: espressif-idf

I wanted to build/compile this project: https://github.com/ETS-PoliTO/esp32-sniffer using ESP32 IDF.

While using the 'idf.py build' command in the given directory, I get the following error:

`CMake Error at C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.0.1/tools/cmake/build.cmake:245 (message):
Failed to resolve component 'nghttp'.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.0.1/tools/cmake/build.cmake:281 (__build_resolve_and_add_req)
C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.0.1/tools/cmake/build.cmake:574 (__build_expand_requirements)
C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.0.1/tools/cmake/project.cmake:440 (idf_build_process)
CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/main/esp32-sniffer-master/esp32-sniffer-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

HINT: The component nghttp could not be found. This could be because: component name was misspelled, the component was not added to the build, the component has been moved to the IDF component manager or has been removed and refactored into some other component.
Please look out for component in 'https://components.espressif.com' and add using 'idf.py add-dependency' command.
Refer to the migration guide for more details about moved components.
Refer to the build-system guide for more details about how components are found and included in the build.`

Since this is kind of a more generic question for the whole ESP32-IDF suite, I thought of sharing the question here.

I've already installed nghttp via 'idf.py add-dependency "espressif/nghttp^1.50.0"', but the same error still exists.

Install 'idf.py add-dependency "espressif/nghttp^1.50.0"', but same error still exists.